# How do you call repository from another repository if Unit of Work contains all repositories?

Tags: c#, .net

I have Generic Repository implemented using Unit of Work and EF.

Lets say I have a CustomerRepository that needs to use ProductRepository inside its body.

The problem is that I use Unit of Work instance to call any specific repository,
so in order to call ProductRepository inside CustomerRepository I would need to pass Unit of Work instance inside that repository which looks like a big code smell to me, because UOW is what originally has and calls repository in the first place.

What would be the best approach if I need to call repository inside another repository? (considering Uow class has both of them)?

Comment: I dont think, ideally, that your repos should know about eachother within the UOW. Maybe refactor into one repository, or pull out that call into it's own repository?

Comment: Agree with @Jonesy, it's easy to solve with an IoC but the root problem is something else.

Comment: How  would you solve it with IoC?

Comment: The reason I am trying to do it this way is because data in repositories comes from XML file. Each repository essentially transforms data from XML nodes into EF entity. Now,  when the node contains several related EF entities I need to essentially transform XML nodes using nested repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I implement what I call *domain transitions pattern*.

My units of work have an additional method called `TransitionTo` and its signature looks like this:

```
IUnitOfWork<TDomainObject> TransitionTo<TDomainObject>()
```

Thanks to *inversion of control*, I implement and get tech-specific units of work and repositories using a container like Castle Windsor. For example, Entity Framework would have an `EFUnitOfWork` and `EFGenericRepository` implementations, and *what represents a transaction within Entity Framework world?* **The `DbContext`**.

The *unit of work* which starts a domain operation is the one instantiating and owning an underlying `DbContext`. `TransitionTo` method in *units of work* must get a *tech-specific unit of work implementation*, and it must also *inject* (dependency injection!) previous unit of work's underlying `DbContext` behind the scene. **That is, the next unit of work can accumulate new operations as part of the high-level domain transaction!**.

The whole pattern pseudo-code looks like the following code:

```
// Unit of work also implements IDisposable so "using" blocks can be used
// to discard changes if code doesn't commit changes
using(IUnitOfWork<T> uow1 = ...)
{
     // Some stuff like accessing unit of work's repository...

     // Then, here's the domain transition to other unit of work:
     using(IUnitOfWork<T2> uow2 = uow1.TransitionTo<T2>())
     {
          // Some other stuff using uow2

          using(IUnitOfWork<TN> uow3 = uow2.TransitionTo<TN>()
          {

          }

     }

     await uow1.CommitAsync();
}
```

This way, you can implement high-level domain transactions and let your code be 100% agnostic from the underlying data-mapping technology (Entity Framework, NHibernate, Dapper).

Comment: A very interesting approach. I didn't think about instantianting other UOWs. However, how exactly would you inject DbContext from uow1 to uow2? Could you provide implementation of TransitionTo by any chance?

Comment: @Tanuki SO isn't a coding service.... BTW I can give you a hint: your units of work should have an associated `DbContext`, thus, when you create a new unit of work using the `TransitionTo` method, you simply associate the same `DbContext` of the previous unit of work, and so on.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer There is still some confusion, whether the above code block we need to write in repositories or Business layer or controllers. I doubt that we can write something like that in the repositories, and I am of the view it should be implicitly accessible, except i don't yet know how.

Comment: @DivTiwari Hey, it's me from 2015 ;-) So, this would be used in services rather than views. If you need collaboration of many services in a higher-level transaction, I would implement a façade, and I would inject same UoW to collaborating services.